# Remove note about sudo that appears when opening the terminal

Tags: command-line, sudo

Whenever I open the terminal,

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".  
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

appears before the terminal. How do I get that to go away?

Comment: Interesting. I once saw such a thing, but never on terminal I open myself. How would I get that back if I wanted it?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Once you run a `sudo` command, the file `~/.sudo_as_admin_successful` will be created and the warning will go away. So either run a sudo command, such as `sudo apt-get update` or create the `~/.sudo_as_admin_successful` file manually:

```
touch ~/.sudo_as_admin_successful
```

If you want the warning back for whatever reason, remove `~/.sudo_as_admin_successful`:

```
rm ~/.sudo_as_admin_successful
```

If you want to remove this functionality completely, then see answer above: https://askubuntu.com/a/22646/405408. In short: remove this message from `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Is there a way to remove this functionality completely?

Comment: It is just a test and a message to say "did you know, you can use sudo to run commands as admin".

Comment: I realized about the message once I deleted that file one day, for no reason. thanks

Comment: @nwalke: See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/22646/405408

Answer (score 45):

Maverick? Comment it out: `sudo vim /etc/bash.bashrc`.
The section, commented:

```
# sudo hint
# if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ]; then
#     case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *)
#     if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
#     cat <<-EOF
#     To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
#     See "man sudo_root" for details.
#    
#     EOF
#     fi
#     esac
# fi
```

Finding the file to start:

```
$ sudo grep -R "man sudo_root" /etc
```

The result:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc:   See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

and then scroll though the output until you see which file contains "man sudo_root".

Comment: I was wondering where it was coming from, and this answers it. Thanks!

Comment: @user8290 It doesn't work in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I commented out just like you mentioned, save the file, open the terminal, ran "sudo apt update", went to home folder and saw .sudo_as_admin_successful file. #Bummer I wish what you said actually worked.

Answer (score 5):

This should not happen, unless you did not yet run any command using [sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) (`sudo echo "hello"` should be enough).

If you **did** run a command using `sudo` and you don't see the file `~/.sudo_as_admin_successful`, then you are probably hit by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/706045).

Answer (score 0):

By the way, `touch`-ing `~/.hushlogin` could also be used to disable the behavior.