# How get rid of the terminal message about sudo

Tags: command-line, login, 15.04

After upgrading to 15.04 I get a message with every new terminal to tell me how to use `sudo`:

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

I know that login messages can origin from **[motd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man5/motd.5.html)** or from the login shell executing several files but where does this message come from and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run a command as sudo, e.g.:

```
sudo ls
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks. Where did the message come from (motd, /etc/profile...?)

Comment: @Jakob More infos [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/22614/367165) ;)

Comment: Gefündenes Fressen!  :P  ;-)