# 2 sudo messages on terminal start

Tags: sudo, bashrc

On opening a new xterminal or starting bash in an already running bash, I get a surprising error message 2 times:

```
t201:~ > bash
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

Since I don't invoke bash with sudo, I ask myself, where this might come from.

First suspect is of course ~/.bashrc, where I often add small functions, but `grep su ~/.bashrc` only reveals words containing 'su' like success and support, all of them in comments.

So I used bash -v to invoke bash in a verbose fashion.

This showed me a lot of commands, directly or indirectly triggered from .bashrc, and between the lines this:

```
# sudo hint
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] ; then
    case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *|*\ sudo\ *)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
    cat <<-EOF
    To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
    See "man sudo_root" for details.

    EOF
    fi
    esac
fi
groups
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

except from the 3 lines after fi, this is found in /etc/bash.bashrc

Ok. That's looking for a magic file .sudo_as_admin_successful . I remembered a command

```
 find -empty -delete
```

Issued few hours ago, but in the home directory, not where it should have been issued, but empty files - who cares?

Well, now I care.

I created a new one:

```
t201:~ > touch .sudo_as_admin_successful 
t201:~ > bash
t201:~ >
```

Error is gone. Do I need special permissions on that file? And what is .hushlogin? I don't have this either.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to stop .sudo_as_admin_successful being created?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813942/is-it-possible-to-stop-sudo-as-admin-successful-being-created). As far as I know there's nothing special about the file, its ownership or permissions.

Comment: I've gotten the same message when Gnome-Terminal didn't set up correctly, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/917299/whats-complaining-about-sudo-when-i-open-a-terminal and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1693607

Answer (score 1):

`~/.sudo_as_admin_successful` is an example of a "flag file", where the *existence* of the file is important, not the content. You'll notice, in the script fragment,
that:

- If `~/.sudo_as_admin_successful` exists, (really, "NOT exists" is FALSE) the whole thing is skipped.
- `~/.hushlogin` is another "flag file", whose existence requests login scripts to be extra quiet. It's left over from early days, but, when set by the user, makes the request.
- Then, using the `groups` command to list `$USER`'s groups (try it - type `groups`), check if `$USER` is a member of the `admin` or `sudo` groups.
- Finally, check for an executable `/usr/bin/sudo`.
- Then, if all this is true, issue the hint.

`~/.sudo_as_admin_successful` is set by `/usr/bin/sudo` when you successfully switch to UID 0. Verify: `sudo strings /usr/bin/sudo | grep ".sudo_as_admin_successful"`).

Modern system administration practice would have the file elsewhere, but `sudo` is old (not obsolete), and is developed outside Canonical/Ubuntu. There are pros and cons to moving `~/.sudo_as_admin_successful`. `sudo` is used on all sorts of Linux and Unix systems. It's necessary for it to be compatible with ALL of them, so `~/.sudo_as_admin_successful` is the simplest choice.