# What's complaining about `sudo` when I open a terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

Recently (since the reboot at Tue 2017-05-09 15:40:28 EDT?), when I open a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, or a terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (`gnome-terminal`,LightDM), the first text I see is:

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

This message is coming from `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which is `source`d by `/etc/profile`. It's generated conditionally:

```
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] ; then
    case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *|*\ sudo\ *)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
        cat <<-EOF
        To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
        See "man sudo_root" for details.

        EOF
    fi
    esac
fi
```

But, my `$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful` exists, and has since Nov 15:

```
$ ll .sudo_as_admin_successful
-rw------- 1 w3 walt 0 Nov 15  2016 .sudo_as_admin_successful
```

and `groups` says I'm in `walt root adm tty lp mail dialout cdrom sudo dip video plugdev lpadmin sambashare wireshark libvirtd` (Note `sudo`).

More detail, in response to comments (I'm not logged in as "another user"

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ id
uid=1003(w3) gid=1000(walt) groups=1000(walt),0(root),4(adm),5(tty),7(lp),8(mail),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare),149(wireshark),152(libvirtd)
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ pathlld $HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root 4096 May 18 20:46 /
/dev/sdb5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Sep  1  2015 /home
/dev/sdb6 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
drwx------ 191 w3 walt 147456 May 21 01:38 /home/w3
/home/.ecryptfs/w3/.Private on /home/w3 type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=e377cfa845240aa1,ecryptfs_sig=5fa903fe1f605483,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
-rw------- 1 w3 walt 0 Nov 15  2016 /home/w3/.sudo_as_admin_successful
```

Why am I getting this message? I've looked at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22607/remove-note-about-sudo-that-appears-when-opening-the-terminal), but it doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: What's `.hushlogin`? That file needs to exist too apparently. I have no mention of it in my `.bashrc`

Comment: @waltinator - did the message start to appear only recently?

Comment: @Zanna - The file .hushlogin in ~ directory disables login welcome messages for bash shell [coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/h2po9w/hushlogin) and [ibm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/suppress_login_msgs.htm)

Comment: Nothing is trying to `sudo`, it's just a message telling you that you can. The assumption in question title is incorrect.

Comment: I'm trying to find out why the message is issued. I can run it in a terminal with no message. What does it think is different at terminal start time?

Comment: Just an idea... What is the value of $HOME ? You are probably logged in as another user?

Comment: Another idea: in my case I have the following ownership and permissions `-rw-r--r-- 1 mook mook 0 Nov 21 02:49 .sudo_as_admin_successful`

Comment: @Zanna no, the file doesn't need to exit - the presence of either file is enough. ((NOT fileA) AND (NOT fileB)) == (NOT (fileA OR fileB)). waltinator: Run `PS4='${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}    ' bash -x` and add the output, please.

Comment: Sorry, @muru but `bash -x` does NOT reproduce the problem. The emitter of the problem text (`/etc/bash.bashrc`) is sourced long before I could set `PS4` (nice trick, though). I _could_ *temporarily* set `PS4` in `/etc/profile` (very carefully), I suppose.

Comment: @waltinator uh, just run the command as I showed it. `/etc/profile` is irrelevant unless you're running a login shell, which gnome terminal doesn't, by default

Comment: Since the message comes from `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which is ONLY AFAIK called from `/etc/profile`, and my gnome-terminal Default preferences do not have "Run command as a login shell" checked, is my Q really "Why is gnome-terminal` starting everything as a login shell"?

Comment: `If Bash is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the -p option is not supplied, no startup files are read, shell functions are not inherited from the environment, the SHELLOPTS, BASHOPTS, CDPATH, and GLOBIGNORE variables, if they appear in the environment, are ignored, and the effective user id is set to the real user id. If the -p option is supplied at invocation, the startup behavior is the same, but the effective user id is not reset` Found at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: @mook765 True, since but my startup files (`/etc/profile` -> `/etc/bash.bashrc` (message), `$HOME/.bashrc`) ARE executed, and I haven't changed anything group-related since Nov 15 (added `epmd` group), I'm confused on how your comment applies.

Comment: I admit that I don't understand all that fully. I also see that your startup files are executed. But the message is triggered according to the conditions in the script in `/etc/ bash.bashrc`. Does a file `/home/walt/.sudo_as_ad...` exist? If not, you could create it, just to track the problem. This is really a hard nut!

Comment: `HOME` is a variable and it's value could change. To see the value of `HOME` at the moment `/etc/bash.bashrc` is running you could add the line `echo "$HOME"` just above the provided snippet of the file. After adding this line open a new terminal and you will see in which directory `bash.bashrc` is looking for the files `.sudo_as_admin_successful` and `.hushlogin`. I think this will give us a clue.

Comment: In setting up for editing `/etc/profile`, I started another `gnome-terminal` (`Ctrl-Alt-T`) which did NOT exhibit the problem. More thought is needed - one of my long-ago implemented self-watching hacks told me that, in the bad `gnome-terminal` I had 10 env vars, and in the good one, 65.

Comment: After moving my `.profile` and `.bashrc` aside, I found that the `gnome-terminal` that complains was started with an environment consisting ONLY of: `DISPLAY=:0`,`PWD=/home/w3`,`SHLVL=1`,`TERM=xterm-256color`,`VTE_VERSION=4205`,`WINDOWID=67108874`. No `HOME`! This is a bug report, not an AskUbuntu Q, I think.

Comment: @mook765 The bug report is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1693607

Comment: @muru The bug report is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1693607

Comment: @waltinator Look at line 109 of `JournalError.txt`: `dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0123\x2d4567.device: Dev dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0123\x2d4567.device appeared twice with different sysfs paths`. I think that is not related to the problem but maybe something you should look at. There are also several errors about `pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error`, that could probably be a point. But that's above my horizon, I will follow your bug-report with interest.